# Quartz.NET inconsistent behavior with non-concurrent misfires

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I've been trying out the DisallowConcurrentExecution-functionality in Quartz.NET but I'm finding it behaves a bit strange.

Say I have a Quartz.NET Job scheduled to run every 1 minute. It then sleeps for 90 seconds and finishes. The [DisallowConcurrentExecution] attribute makes sure all but the first executions will misfire.

What I want to happen is that as soon as the scheduler is free (at 1:30), the next Job executes, and when that one finishes (at 3 min) the next one kicks off, and so on. Instead what I'm finding is this:

[image]

It does what I want only half of the time, every other time the scheduler just hangs around idle for a full minute while it is missing more and more executions.

After a bit of reading I thought this was the doing of the 'smart policy', the default misfire handling technique. I tried setting specific ones, but they did not achieve what I stated above. Even the `WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNowWithRemainingCount()` did not work (see screenshot), which according to the Java version's [docs](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html#MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NOW_WITH_REMAINING_REPEAT_COUNT) should

> re-schedule 'now' (...) with the repeat count set to what it would be, if
>   it had not missed any firings.

So am I missing something, another option or caveat, or is this a bug on Quartz' end? If the latter, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the full minute idle time was due to the `misfireThreshold` property, which is 60 seconds by default. I'll be setting it to e.g. 5 seconds, as below:

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection
{
    ["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "5000"
};
```

I'm unsure about why the misfirethreshold would need to delay retries in this case, as after some minutes there are more and more misfired executions who have already waited more than 60 seconds. It probably could be considered a bug. Luckily, the workaround for this specific problem is easy enough.